# How to determine linear dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have a set $(i + 2j, i + 3j, i, j)$, I can tell that they are dependent.

What if I have a set $(i + 2j, i + 3j, i, j, k)$?

By definition, $c_1v_1+...+c_nv_n = 0$ as long as not all of them are zero

Does that mean the 2nd set is also linear dependent? However, '$k$' can never be written as a combination of the rest of the vector.

Comment: $i+2j-(i+3j)+j=0$ so they're linearly dependent

Comment: The most effective method is using a matrix whose columns comprise these vectors and determining if it is column-full-rank.

Answer (score 0):

See that
$$
0(i+2j)+1(i+3j)-1(i)-3(j)+0(k)=0.
$$
Since some of the coefficients are non zero the set is linearly dependent by the definition.

It doesn't matter that $k$ cannot be written as a combination of the others as some of the other vectors in the set can be still written as some combination each other.

Answer (score 0):

A set is linearly dependent if and only if

> **at least one** of the vectors in the set is a linear combination of the others.

You appear to be assuming that this is the case if and only if

> **every** vector in the set is a linear combination of the others

which is not true.